# Does useState change on every render?

Tags: reactjs

Will setState objects be everytime the same on every rerended, so I can pass them safely as i.e. useCallback's dependencies, and they won't cause
any rerenders when the component is rerendered?

Comment: Correct.  The value will only change when you have called setState.

Comment: Why don't you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. React keeps the same object reference as you assigned.

Further more, even if you call `setState` with the same object reference, React will still keep it referential equal, and even [skips the re-render](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-caveats) (if it's not necessary for other reasons).